# Anacron - Python subprocess not executing gdrive command

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have been using the ubuntu gdrive command line tool to push some of my files to Google Drive; however, recently I wrote a python script that automates the process:
(gdrive command line: http://www.howopensource.com/2015/01/google-drive-for-ubuntu-linux/ )

```
# Push to Google Drive
str_output = "\tPushing "
cmd_push = ("drive push -ignore-conflict {0}/").format(dir_db_full)
if dict_args['type'] == now:
    str_output += "zip file "
    cmd_push += zip_db
else:
    str_output += ("\"{0}\" directory ").format(dict_args['type'])
    cmd_push += dir_final + "/"
str_output += "to Google Drive..."
print str_output

cmd_push = ('export GOPATH=$HOME/go ; export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin ; yes | {0} ').format(cmd_push)
subprocess.call( cmd_push, shell=True)
```

This works!

When I run it via anacron, the whole python script runs, but seems to improperly run the subprocess.call; as in, it does not push the file to Google Drive.  Here is my anacron file:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron
# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
7       1       week          sudo /usr/bin/python /srv/bin/backup.py -type week >> /srv/bin/log/log_backup.txt
@monthly 20     month         sudo /usr/bin/python /srv/bin/backup.py -type month >> /srv/bin/log/log_backup.txt
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

No errors are reported; anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened to reside 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go'.  Using a tutorial, I placed the 'go' package under my home path instead of a directory that was user-independent; hence, when the script ran as 'root', it had issues finding the 'go' package.  The output passed from the script to the log file did not contain the error that the 'drive' command was not found.